# Intermittent power failure in hot weather 2007 Escalade

Tags: electrical, starting, troubleshooting, cadillac

We have a 2007 Escalade with 160k miles. The car runs great normally, but when the weather gets hot, an array of warning lights will come on from time to time, the power will drop for a moment (radio stops, etc. for less than 1 second) and we resume.

Occasionally however, when I get home, I'll get back in and no electric - can't turn it over, no interior lights, running boards stay down (they are electric).

Usually, if I move the battery terminals around and climb back in the car, things start back up no problem. Mechanic says the terminals look fine and the battery checked out. Is there anything else it could be?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does the car have any circuit breakers? When it fails to start at home have you ever just let it sit and come back to find that it's working again?

Comment: I should have updated this after I found out. Even though the battery initially tested good, the next mechanic put it under load and was able to get it to fail. Replaced battery and no more problems. Interestingly, the fuel pump went bad three days later - I wonder if it could be related somehow (underpowered the. Overpowered, etc..)

Comment: Thanks for the update, it is nice to know how these things get resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad battery, even though it initially tested well.